# How to copy a database row from one table to other table in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want copy a row of data from one table to other. The table from i want to copy has id, name, password fields. The table where the values should be copied has id, name, password, post_count fields.

I am trying to use the following code but its not helping.

```
$data=$this->Register->find(null, $id);
if($this->User->save($data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data copied'), true);
}
```

What should i do??

I have already removed the validations of the table where i want to copy the values to to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear sir froyo, with all due respect, could you tell us what error message is shown / the problem you are facing etc.

Comment: are you able to access `register` and `user` models from your (register) controller? Via `App::import()` or through the associations

Answer (score 1):

The query `$this->Register->find(null, $id);` returns data in some different format. Instead I changed the query. The code is below

```
$condition = array('id'=>$id);
$data=$this->Register->find('first', array('conditions'=>$condition));
$newdata = array(
            'User' => array(
                'name' => $data['Register']['name'],
                'password' => $data['Register']['password']
       )
);
if($this->User->save($newdata)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data copied'), true);
}
```

This works as the return of the find('first') returns an array which can be modified as per our needs and then we can call the save method of User model.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$data = $this->Register->read(null, $id);

$newdata = array();
$newdata = array(
          'User' => array(
                      'name' => $data['Register']['name'],
                      'password' => $data['Register']['password']
                   )
        );
// If you are in Register controller then import User model 

if($this->User->save($newdata, false)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data copied'), true);
}
```

Comment: No error message is shown and nothing is copied from one table to other.

Comment: The find query returns the whole field i.e id, name, password and while saving this all these values are saved. Only name and password need to be saved and not the other fields.

Comment: no it didnt workout.
Should this line be included before a call to save method.
    `$this->User->create();`

Comment: Following error is there.
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1048: Column 'name' cannot be null [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
Query: INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)

Comment: @froyo.max I updated my answer and if now any error occur then post the data you got from Register and also the error

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this isn't working for you is because the Register record by that ID doesn't exist. You must check if the results contain data before attempting to save it. This is why you get NULL,NULL in the INSERT statement.

```
$record = $this->Register->findById($id);
if(!empty($record))
{
   $this->User->create();
   if($this->User->save(array('User'=>$record['Register']),false,array('name','password')))
   {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data copied'), true);
   }
}
else
{
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data not found'), true);
}
```